# How to replace html text in livecode

Tags: livecode

Iam using this code for replace a word with the same word with strike. Its works fine.

```
replace Str[1] with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" in myHtml
```

But when i replace it vice versa its not working. Iam using this code fore replacing

```
replace "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" with Str[1] in myHtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually works for me. it strikes and colours the "def" on the first  `answer`but it is back to normal on the second. Maybe you have some issue with escaping the `quotes`?

```
 put "abc def"  into myHtml
 put "def" into Str[1]
replace Str[1] with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" in myHtml
answer myHtml -- "def" is yellow and stroke
replace "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" with Str[1] in myHtml 
answer myHtml -- "def" is back to normal text
```

Comment: Yes. that code works. I write this two replace in two buttons. [put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml   replace Str[1] with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" in myHtml  set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml] it is the code of first button and [put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml   replace "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" with Str[1] in myHtml  set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml] this is the code of second button. Its not working.

Comment: I just rebuilt your example with the two buttons and it seems that `yellow` gets converted to the html color code. so this works in the second button:        `replace "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "#FFFF00" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" with Str[1] in myHtml `

Comment: Thank you very much @ Tate. This code is working fine.

Comment: Is there any way to find the stroke word in text field.

Answer (score 0):

Working example with two Buttons and one text field:

Button 1:

```
on mouseUp
put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml 
put item 1 of myhtml into str[1]
replace Str[1] with "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" in myHtml 
set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
end mouseUp
```

Button 2:

```
on mouseUp
put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml 
 put "abc" into str[1]
replace "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "#FFFF00" & quote & ">" & Str[1] & "</font></strike>" with Str[1] in myHtml 
set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml
end mouseUp
```

and how I set my textfield

```
set the htmltext of field "mytextfield" to "abc,def"
```